# Unable to get a system variable work for manuals

Tags: zsh, manuals, system-variable

I have the following system variable in .zshrc

```
manuals='/usr/share/man/man<1-9>'
```

I run unsuccessfully

```
zgrep -c compinit $manuals/zsh*
```

I get

```
zsh: no matches found: /usr/share/man/man<1-9>/zsh*
```

The command should be the same as the following command which works

```
zgrep -c compinit /usr/share/man/man<1-9>/zsh*
```

**How can you run the above command with a system variable in Zsh?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my investigations, it looks like zsh performs `<>` substitution *before* `$` substitution. That means when you use the `$` variant, it first tries `<>` substitution (nothing there) then `$` substitution (which works), and you're left with the string containing the `<>` characters.

When you don't use `$manuals`, it first tries `<>` substitution and it works. It's a matter of order. The final version below shows how to defer expansion so they happen at the same time:

These can be seen here:

```
> manuals='/usr/share/man/man<1-9>'

> echo $manuals
  /usr/share/man/man<1-9>

> echo /usr/share/man/man<1-9>
  /usr/share/man/man1 /usr/share/man/man2 /usr/share/man/man3
  /usr/share/man/man4 /usr/share/man/man5 /usr/share/man/man6
  /usr/share/man/man7 /usr/share/man/man8

> echo $~manuals
  /usr/share/man/man1 /usr/share/man/man2 /usr/share/man/man3
  /usr/share/man/man4 /usr/share/man/man5 /usr/share/man/man6
  /usr/share/man/man7 /usr/share/man/man8
```

Comment: I this time accept Pax's answer because of great examples. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$> manuals=/usr/share/man/man<0-9>
$> zgrep -c compinit ${~manuals}/zsh*
```

The '~' tells zsh to perform expansion of the `<0-9>` when using the variable. The zsh reference card tells you how to do this and more.

Comment: @sykora: Do you know how you can put these folders to be run for run-help, such that I can search the help files by just typing $ compinit Esc-h?